# What exactly are the rules of the "grace period" regarding answering a question that has been closed?

Tags: discussion, grace-period

More than few times already, I start typing an answer to a question that gets closed in the meantime. I get the yellow notification and the "post answer" button is disabled.

When I later come back to the question I notice that someone else managed to post an answer with the timestamp being few minutes **after** the question closed.

Are there specific rules for the "grace period"?

A quick example. An answer was posted 30 minutes after the question got closed by a non-admin user:
[How to get this "text disappearing" effect on span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252385/how-to-get-this-text-disappearing-effect-on-span)

Comment: I hope that you was not writing a lengthy, informative answer that took 5+ minutes to witness that stupid notification being shown (question got closed due of "opinion based") like I have experienced once.

Comment: someone did it after 30min from the closure: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58252385/8620333 .. not sure how, but it's was done

Comment: @KarelG Unfortunately I can't say that this didn't happen

Comment: This indicates it's 4 hours, if it's still to date but one answer is only about a year old: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for the example, I will use it as an example in the OP

Comment: @Magisch It's not a duplicate. That question does not provide any info about the rules. I know that such "server-side grace period" exists but it never seems to work for me

Comment: @DeepSpace I added a second dupe, which also has the MSE dupe with the numbers in it.

Comment: Further reading about how it evolved over time here on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/308386

Comment: I have a theory that lower rep users have a better chance of getting the answer submitted than higher rep users. Just an observation I've made over time but have nothing empirical to support this theory

Comment: One word for you: Inspect Element.